# Skipping already updated row

Tags: sql-server

I would like to update a table column with a counter stored in a another table that is incremented on each update. All is working fine. However, if I reset the counter to a new number that happens to already exist in the table to update, for example,  7; during the update, it will find the 7 we updated in the first loop and update it along with other values of 7.
Is there a way to skip already updated values and only update those that are not? I am contemplating adding a column with a flag to track already updated rows; which I delete after the update. However, I feel there could be a better way of doing this. Any ideas?
This is what I currently have:

```
/**counter table**/
create table ctl (cid int)
insert into ctl values (1)

/**table to update**/
create table tbl1(tid int)
insert into tbl1 (tid)
values(1),(1),(1),(1),(2),(3),(3),(3),(3),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(7)

/**temp table**/
select tid into #tmptbl from tbl1

declare @tidNum int
declare @cctl int

select @cctl = (select cid from ctl)

while exists (select tid from #tmptbl)
begin

select @tidNum = (select top 1 tid from #tmptbl order by tid asc)

update tbl1 set tid=@cctl where tid=@tidNum
select @cctl=@cctl+1
update  ctl set cid=@cctl

delete #tmptbl where tid=@tidNum

end
select * from tbl1
drop table #tmptbl
```

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) in so many ways. Firstly you state this *"with a counter stored in a another table that is incremented on each update"*. This is a pretty big red flag. You will get race conditions, locking problems, and undesired behaviour here. A `SEQUENCE` would be a far better option. Next, you're using a `WHILE` but writing SQL. SQL is a set-based language and it's *awful* at iterative tasks. You're trying to apply a programmatical solution with a query language. Personally, it seems you would be better off telling us what your *actual* goal is here.

Comment: Thank you Larnu.
I need to reset a control number on an existing table. This control number is tracked in another table as it can be used in multiple tables. What I have currently is working, but I foresee the problem described.

Comment: Also, how do *you* know that a row has already been updated? If the rows have already been updated, why is the pseudo-`SEQUENCE` being reset?

Comment: *"this control number is tracked in another table as it can be used in multiple tables."* Oh, this is definitely a bigger problem that I thought then. Why are you updating all these tables iteratively anyway? That doesn't make sense; like i said you're using SQL, not C#.

Comment: My current approach is as follows
I create a temp table from the table to be updated,
Loop through the temp table,
   Select the first row from the temp table, in ascending order,
   Update all in the table to be updated where equals the selected row in temp data,
   Increment the counter table,
   Delete from the temp table the selected selected row;
Loop until all rows in temp data are deleted...

Comment: That tells me what you're doing, not what the problem you're trying to solve is. Like I said, this has [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) written all over it. Tell us the *real* problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the *actual* problem that needs to be solved isn't outlined in the question. This is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/397219). Without knowing the actual problem to solve, users cannot give an answer, or it would likely not actually solve the *real* problem the user has. The question needs to be amended to describe the underlying problem.

Comment: It doesn't even sound like a `SEQUENCE` is needed in the end; sounds like you need a set-based solution. But you don't give us any details of the ***real*** problem (you're still yet to respond to my initial questions of *"
Also, how do* you *know that a row has already been updated"*). We can't help you if we don't know the problem.

Comment: Ok; thanks for your input. May be someone else will get what I am after. And word of advice, jumping to close a question just because YOU do not understand it shouldn't be the way to help.

Comment: The reason I "don't" understand is because *you* haven't explained... I've asked you questions you've refused to answer, if you won't explain the problem how can you hope that others will fix it? I (and every other user) can't see what you see, access your instance, talk to your colleages to get their requirements, or read your mind. You *need* to explain and if you won't, then help can't be provided. You're asking people to use their **free** time to help you, but won't *help us* help **you**. If you can't explain the problem, what hope do we have of understanding it? None.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/**counter table**/
create table ctl (cid int)
insert into ctl values (1)

/**table to update**/
create table tbl1(tid int)
insert into tbl1 (tid)
values(1),(1),(1),(1),(2),(3),(3),(3),(3),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(7)
go

begin transaction 

declare @foo table(cid int);
declare @base int;

update ctl
set cid = cid + (select count(distinct tid) from tbl1)
output deleted.cid into @foo(cid);

select @base = cid
from @foo;

update t
set tid = addme + thebase
from
(
select tid, dense_rank() over(order by tid)-1 as addme, @base as thebase
from tbl1
) as t

--error handling goes here
commit transaction
go

select *
from tbl1;

update ctl
set cid = 4;
go

begin transaction

declare @foo table(cid int)
declare @base int

update ctl
set cid = cid + (select count(distinct tid) from tbl1)
output deleted.cid into @foo(cid);

select @base = cid
from @foo

update t
set tid = addme + thebase
from
(
select tid, dense_rank() over(order by tid)-1 as addme, @base as thebase
from tbl1
) as t

--error handling goes here
commit transaction
go

select *
from tbl1;
go
```

Comment: Thank you lptr! This is exactly what I was looking for. As the OP, I mark this as the answer.
I have no idea why someone would downvote this answer though..
Thank you for your time.